# HTML Table SBadmin Bootstrap From JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, datatables, bootstrapping

I am trying to build a table from JSON but it is not loading the data properly . I want pagination in the table . I tried to followed the format from SB Admin Bootstrap but it fails to load any data .

My HTML Code is :--

```
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="agents">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th> employeeNumber</th>
     <th> fullName</th>
     <th>employeeEmail</th>
     <th>jobTitle</th>
     <th>deptNo</th>
     <th>deptName</th>
     <th>managerEmail</th>
     <th>managerId</th>
     <th>managerName</th>
     <th>assignmentLastModifiedBy</th>
     <th>assignmentLastModifiedDate</th>
     <th>country</th>
     <th>theatre</th>
     <th>paymentAnalyst</th>
     <th>commDateFrom</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

My Script is :--

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#agents').dataTable( {
  "ajax": 'http://localhost:8080/TestQuartz/json/agent.json'
    } );
    } );
</script>
```

My JSON File is :--

```
{"agent":[
{"country":"AUS","employeeNumber":"397142","assignmentLastModifiedBy":null,"assignmentLastModifiedDate":null,"paymentAnalyst":"Khoo, T","fullName":"ABC","theatre":"ASIA","managerId":"249058","commDateFrom":"2015-06-15 00:00:00.0","deptName":"Global Virtual Sales - ","managerName":"Turner, J","jobTitle":"VIRTUAL SALES ACCOUNT ","managerEmail":"ert","deptNo":"115331063","employeeEmail":"bre"},
{"country":"DEU","employeeNumber":"196091","assignmentLastModifiedBy":null,"assignmentLastModifiedDate":null,"paymentAnalyst":"Hatlak, T","fullName":"Gros, S","theatre":"EURO","managerId":"52367","commDateFrom":"2006-11-01 00:00:00.0","deptName":"Global Virtual Sales - Germany HQ","managerName":"Mer, W","jobTitle":"TERRITORY BUSINESS MANAGER.III.SALES.XYZ","managerEmail":"wme","deptNo":"515031281","employeeEmail":"sim"},
{"country":"FIN","employeeNumber":"598401","assignmentLastModifiedBy":null,"assignmentLastModifiedDate":null,"paymentAnalyst":"Hatlak, T","fullName":"Kur, Es","theatre":"EURO","managerId":"144218","commDateFrom":"2011-10-01 00:00:00.0","deptName":"EU SS Geo Finland OTHER","managerName":"Lunt, Tha","jobTitle":"CLIENT SERVICES MANAGER.II.SERVICE SALES.XYZ","managerEmail":"tlu","deptNo":"561038082","employeeEmail":"eku"},
{"country":"USA","employeeNumber":"399411","assignmentLastModifiedBy":null,"assignmentLastModifiedDate":null,"paymentAnalyst":"Spaulding, S,"fullName":"Hen, Cr Jo","theatre":"US","managerId":"153592","commDateFrom":"2015-06-22 00:00:00.0","deptName":"Michigan Select","managerName":"Wil, Sc A","jobTitle":"SYSTEMS ENGINEER-C.II.SALES.XYZ","managerEmail":"sco","deptNo":"020230434","employeeEmail":"cra"}
]}
```

Can anyone help me with it ?

Regards.

Comment: Don't you need a tbody element?

Comment: Ideally the bootstrap loads the tbody automatically based in the script .

Comment: Try changing the `agent` in your json file to `data`, or add a `'dataSrc': 'agent'` parameter to your AJAX request

Comment: as @vogomatix said you need the `<tbody>` tag empty in order to fill the datatable

Comment: change ajax with sAjaxSource. Which version of datatable are you using

Comment: Proposed solution below - there appear to be two main issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is pulled from an `agent` object instead of a `data` object, so you need a `dataSrc`. Also, instead of getting data from arrays, you are getting data from objects, so you need to use the columns `data` option.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#agents').dataTable( {
     "ajax": 'http://localhost:8080/TestQuartz/json/agent.json',
     "dataSrc": "agent",
     "columns": [
         { "data" : "employeeNumber"},
         { "data" : "fullName" },
         ....
         { "data" : "commDateFrom" }
     ]
  } );
} );
</script>
```

As far as styling goes, remember to use the [Datatables Bootstrap integration](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) files. The CSS is a replacement for the standard Datatables CSS - you don't need both.

Comment: Thank you for your help . One more doubt .. I am trying to keep width for table constant but it not working any idea on same  ..

Comment: Add class="table" to the table element. If you're using bootstrap this should be picked up and the table should be the full width of the containing div

Comment: Added more info at the bottom of my answer

Comment: I was able to fix it using scroll functionality .. But sorting is getting auto selected as another row ...moreover if i pass the width of the columns separately it is not allowing it  ...